# Global.asax and user visits

Tags: global-asax

I'm trying to dig around into an idea where we want to close a webiste for upgrades. So when a user hits our site, they are promptly re-directed to a page that tells them that the site is down for maintenance.

Theoretically, the entire process starts in the global.asax under the event session_start. We fire a command to the webservice to see if the service is down - if it is down, a false value is returned and the user is rerouted to a page that says the site is down otherwise normal operations continue. This is a non-password site.

Here's the idea with pages:

welcome.aspx
siteisdown.aspx
page1.aspx
page2.aspx

When the user visits the site, the code checks to see if the rest of the site is down for maintenance and if so, then the user is re-routed to siteisdown.aspx

We have that basic part down - but the real understanding is, the user - while still in the siteisdown.aspx page, could enter page1.aspx and continue on their merry way.

What we want to is is if the user enters page1.aspx they should be kicked back to siteisdown.aspx

What articles should I be looking at for this type of method? Forms Authentication?

Answer (score 0):

There is already a feature for this built in. Deploy a static HTML file called "App_Offline.htm" to the root of your application and all requests will be routed there.

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/10/06/426755.aspx